# Есть ли программа по поиску определенного изображения из базы данных?

Tags: база-данных, поиск-программ, параметры

Всем привет! Я все не могу найти какую-нибудь программку, которая могла бы среди определенной базы данных с изображениями найти определенное по некоторым параметрам (типа качество, яркость и т.п.). Есть ли что-то подходящее?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.